# how to serialize the myCount variable?

Tags: java, thread-safety

How can I serialize myCount variable that each thread increment it in exclusive mode ? later next thread increment it based on new value of myCount?  so myCount will be increased by threads one by one in turns ?

Currently my result as the following:

```
    starting main thread----
    -----this is Main1
    ex Thread:2
    ex Thread:3
    -----this is Main3
    ex Thread:4
    -----this is Main4
    ex Thread:5
    -----this is Main5
    -----this is Main6
    ex Thread:7
    -----this is Main8
    ex Thread:9
    -----this is Main10
    ex Thread:11
```

---------------code -------------------

```
    class MySamThread extends Thread {
    public static int myCount=0;
    public void run() {
    while(MySamThread.myCount<=10){
        try{System.out.println("ex Thread:"+(++MySamThread.myCount));
            Thread.sleep(100);          
        }catch (InterruptedException iex){
        System.out. println("exception in thread:"+iex.getMessage());}
        }}}


    public class RunSamThread {
    public static void main (String a[]){
    System.out.println("starting main thread----");
    MySamThread mst=new MySamThread();
    mst.start();
    while(MySamThread.myCount<=10){
      try{
          System.out.println("-----this is Main"+  
    (++MySamThread.myCount));
          Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException iex){``
          System.out.println("exception in main   
   thread"+iex.getMessage());}    
    }}}
```

Thank you so much for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to synchronize and not serialize?

you can add a method in MySamThread  as follows
`public static synchronized int incrementCount() {
    return ++mycount;
}`

 and instead of calling `++MySamThread.myCount` from main and the thread, call `MySamThread.incrementCount()`
This will ensure that only one thread increments the count at a time.

Comment: @Lulu's use of serialize is appropriate, though I might say, "serialize access to myCount".

Comment: Very Sorry for late response! I am just  back to the forum today. I will try it based on your helps here. Thank you so much for your kindly reply here!